# how to fetch 1 by 1 record from table in db2

Tags: sql, db2

```
sno acco_no amount

1    50001     5000
2    50002     4000
3    50001     2500
4    50002     3100
5    50002     3400
6    50001     1500
```

in which i want to take 50001's last 2 records **one by one.**

ie is result'd be :

```
sno acco_no amount
6 50001 1500-----> i want to move this record to variable1
3 50001 2500-----> i want to move this record to variable2
```

pls help me anyone

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get only the last 2 records

```
select *
from tbl
where acco_no = 50001
order by sno desc
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

Then in your code, store the first record into var 1 and the 2nd into var 2.

Comment: @user659907: Could you clarify what you mean by "1 by 1"? Do you want both rows in a single row, as in (sno, acco_no, amount, sno2, acco_no2, amount2)?